# Why is project default list empty in nuget console? Also link to manage nuget packages is disabled

Tags: nuget, nuget-package, visual-studio-2017

As title says, how do I fix this? I have tried every solution I could find here.
Im using `Visual Studio Community 2017 RC`

Comment: Do you use VS2017 version 15.0.26020.0? Cannot reproduce your problem. What is the reproduction path?

Comment: Yes the same. What is reproduction path?

Comment: What kind of project do you open?

Comment: Django project with bootstrap. What I'm trying to do is update bootstrap from 3 to 4

Comment: Did you try using "Install-Package bootstrap -Version 4.0.0-alpha6 -Pre" (create a backup first)?

Comment: Yes but not able to because the dropdown list in "Project default" is empty. Is it possible outside of VS?

Comment: Finding NuGet.exe: dir /s nuget.exe (from C:\). Open command line in project root. Look at [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/nl-nl/nuget/tools/nuget-exe-cli-reference) documentation.

Comment: What is the NuGet Package Manager VSIX version you are using?